# Binding checkedboxes as objects to be added to a <List> as a field of parent object, to be passed to database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to make a Recipe Builder form using Thymeleaf.
The functionality I am trying to implement involves adding a List of selected objects (ingredients) to the bound recipe.

### Here is a snippet of the Form from the Template file:

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/recipes/userRecipes/new/save}" th:object="${userRecipe}"
            method="post">
...
                    <td>Ingredients:</td>
                    <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li th:each="ingredient : ${allIngredients}">
                            <input type = "checkbox" th:name="sel_ingredients" th:value="${ingredient.id}" />
                            <label th:text="${ingredient.name}">Ingredient</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
...
            </table>
        </form>
```

### Here is a snippet from my controller:

```java
 @RequestMapping("/userRecipes/new")
    public String createNewUserRecipe(Model model){
        UserRecipe userRecipe = new UserRecipe();
        model.addAttribute("userRecipe", userRecipe);
        return "new-recipe";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/userRecipes/new/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveRecipe(
        @ModelAttribute("userRecipe") UserRecipe userRecipe,
        @RequestParam(value = "sel_ingredients", required = false) int[] sel_ingredients,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        for(int i : sel_ingredients){
            Ingredient ing = new Ingredient();
            ing = ingredientRepo.getOne((long)i);
            userRecipe.addIngredient(ing);
        }
        userRecipeRepo.save(userRecipe);
        return "redirect:../";
    }
```

### Along with a @ModelAttribute to set Ingredients:

```java
@ModelAttribute
    public void populateIngredients(Model model){
        List<Ingredient> ingredientList = this.ingredientRepo.findAll();
        //Iterator<Ingredient> itr = ingredientList.iterator();
        model.addAttribute("allIngredients", ingredientList);

    }
```

### Entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_recipes")
public class UserRecipe extends  AuditModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    private String description;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "used_ingred",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_recipe_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredientid")
    )
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    public void addIngredient(Ingredient i){
        this.ingredients.add(i);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    private String preparation;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredients_master")
public class Ingredient extends AuditModel{

    @Column(name = "ingredient")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // public Ingredient(String n, String d){
    //     this.setName(n);
    //     this.setDescription(d);
    // }

    // public Ingredient(int id, String n, String d){
    //     this.setId(id);
    //     this.setName(n);
    //     this.setDescription(d);
    // }


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients")
    Set<UserRecipe> recipes;

    @ManyToMany
    Set<Tag> tags;
```

Originally, I tried to grab the Ingredient objects directly, but couldn't figure out how to do that, so instead opted to grab the ids, and then reference them from the Repository; however,

I get the following error when I click the save button:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.donovanuy.mixmix.entities.UserRecipe.addIngredient(UserRecipe.java:85)
    at com.donovanuy.mixmix.controllers.RecipeController.saveRecipe(RecipeController.java:103)
```

If possible, I'd like to be able to grab the Ingredient object directly, and add it to the List field of my userRecipe.

I am considering making a separate RecipeMakerForm, that I can instead pass into a service. Something like:

```java
public class RecipeMakerForm{
String newTitle;
Long[] ingredientIds;
Long[] tagIds;
```

and the service would like like:

```java
public class RecipeMaker{

void makeRecipe(RecipeMakerForm form){
    Recipe r = new Recipe(form.getNewTitle());
    if (ingredientIds != null){
      for (Long id : ingredientIds){
          r.addIngredient(ingredientRepo.getOne(l));

      }
    //etc

    recipeRepo.save(r);
}
```

Even still, I suspect my errors have something to do with the way Thymeleaf is passing the model data back to the controller, so my new RecipeMaker & RecipeMakerForm methods wouldn't work. I'm still new to using Thymeleaf and working with Spring.data, so I expect my solution to be somewhere in my Thymeleaf or Controller methods.